# How can I avoid jenkins build failed messages moving to spam

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have configured jenkins on Ubuntu server which triggers email on build failure.
The problem is the build failed emails are moving to spam folder for all the receivers.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Configure your email client so the sending address is always delivered to your inbox/safe folder?

Comment: If you have a received message, you may be able to get more information about _why_ it is being recognized as spam by looking in the headers of the message.  That may help you figure out what's triggering it (bad content, bad send address, lack of SPF, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use an official email server or did you install your own on Ubuntu?

If you use an official one, you should, as mentioned above, you should add a rule to your client to allow this messages. If you use your own mail server the messages might be deleted by another instance because it might be a "spam" server